# Desktop Icons are frozen

Tags: windows-xp, desktop-icons

My desktop icons & favorites bar icons have frozen. Is there a driver or command to make them draggable again? I am running XP SP3.

Comment: are they frozen? as in they are not usable? or are they frozen as in not moveable?

Comment: You didn't say what OS you're using, but on Windows there's an Auto Arrange feature that could make it seem like your desktop icons are immovable (if that's what you mean by frozen). You can control it by right-clickling in a blank space on the desktop and selecting Arrange Icons By...

Comment: does your start menu button work? if not, check your desktop wallpaper. your colleagues may be pranking you with a classic (see #9) http://lifehacker.com/373817/top-10-harmless-geek-pranks otherwise, right click the taskbar and uncheck "lock the taskbar", and follow martineau's advice on auto-arrange.

Answer (score 0):

Im gonna assume you mean "frozen" as in "frozen in place".

- Just right-click on the desktop
- Hover over "arrange icons by"
- uncheck the setting for "auto arrange"